# jQuery to change the text of menu

Tags: jquery, html, css

I managed to create a sticky vertical menu that expands when hover using css transitions. I also added functionality so that when clicked it slides to an anchor.

I want this menu to have the following functionality with jquery. When I click on a menu item I want it to change its text from "1." to "title 1" and stay expanded. When I press another menu, the previous one should return it's default state (small width and "1." as text) and the new one to expand and change text from let's say "2." to "title 2". How can I achieve it.

Here is the jQuery I use for the slide function.

```
$(function() {
  $('.slider a').bind('click', function(event) {
  var $anchor = $(this);

  $('html, body').stop().animate({
     scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
  }, 1000);

  event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Here is my fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/mosmic/319d4bcL/

If fiddle seems not to work just expand your browser window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `data-` attribute for that like this.

```
<a href="#section1" data-shortname="1." data-longname="title 1">
    <div class="number">1.</div>
</a>
```

check your updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/319d4bcL/7/